# Is a plane in eye space also a plane in clip space?

Tags: opengl, graphics

say I have given a plane P in eye coordinates in 4D space with origin (x,y,z,1) and normal vector (dx,dy,dz,0).

Is this still a plane in clip space?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Points which are co-planar in camera space will still be co-planar in 4D homogeneous clip space. Indeed, this is also true of points which are co-linear. Indeed, lines which are parallel in camera space are also parallel in 4D homogeneous clip space.

But remember: we're talking about 4D homogeneous clip space. So you're talking about 4-dimensional planes and 4-dimensional lines. That's ultimately not what gets rendered. You render by transforming from 4D clip space into 3D NDC space (and then to window space, but never mind that now).

In NDC space, points that were co-planar and co-linear in camera space will still be co-planar and co-linear in NDC space. But parallel lines *will not* be preserved by the division-by-W transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In reality eyes see to a curve, but in computer graphics we simplify it to a truncated pyramid with a straight bottom / end plate.

Comment: Isn't it a problem that the w_clip coordinate depends on z_eye?

Comment: @user5024425: no, it's not a problem as long as only line bounded primitives are clipped. It would be a problem for curves, but OpenGL doesn't draw curves and because linear maps are homomorphisms, i.e. structure preserving no "funny" things happen.

Comment: I created a plane in eye space, then converted the origin and normal to clip space. Now I want to pick this plane by unprojecting the pixel coordinates to clip space. Will this make sense or should I pick in eye space?